# How to select more than one checkbox in gridview and show the details in another Gridview in asp.net with c#

Tags: asp.net

In my project i have a need to select some check boxes in a GridView and show the details in another gridview. I use an arraylist to keep all the values of the checkbox using the foreach loop, but i can't able to display the records in another Grid view. Any help will be  highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write out the code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample and use as per your requirement

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Navigate" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code

```
private void PassValues()
{ 
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            if (ViewState["CountLimit"] != null)
            {
                counter++;
                ViewState["CountLimit"] = counter;               
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                ViewState["CountLimit"] = counter;
            }
            if (counter < 2)
            {
                //Display message if user selects only 1 item
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowBox", "alert('You should select at least 2 items!');", true);
                //Save the selected items in the Array
                arr.Add(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text);
            }
            else
            {
                //Save the selected items in the Array
                arr.Add(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text);
                //Store the values in Session so that we can get the values on the page
                Session["Values"] = arr;
                //Navigate to the next page
                Response.Redirect("Default4.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PassValues();
}
```

On Page2 write the following code

```
     protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
      if (Session["Values"] != null)
      {
          ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)Session["Values"];
          foreach (string item in arr)
          {
              Response.Write(item + "<BR/>");
          }
      }

   }
```